# IM protocol with message receipt confirmation

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin, protocol

Is there any instant messaging protocol (or plugin for Pidgin) that uses a read receipt layer to verify whether messages have actually been delivered and resend if not? I've had problems recently with AIM and MSN where IMs simply do not get through, and it introduces an unacceptable level of unreliability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["XEP-0184: Message Delivery Receipts"](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html) extension to XMPP does this. It is currently a Draft Standard, but a number of clients appear to support it, including Miranda IM, Gajim, Tkabber, Psi+, and Bombus. There is an [open ticket](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/6940) to add an XEP-0184 plug-in to Pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP (Jabber) has an extension (XEP-203) for that which many clients implement, it does not need modification on the server side. Pidgin supports it.

Comment: So [XEP-0203](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0203.html) ("Delayed Delivery") guarantees that the other end receives your message? It looks like an offline message protocol more than any sort of confirmation. I need to know (reasonably) immediately whether or not the message got through.